# Export MapInfo map to Google Earth (.kml file)

Tags: kml, mapinfo, google-earth, mapbasic

I have a map in MapInfo.

I can convert it to Google Earth file (.kml) manually but I would like to do it automatically by commands in a function.

Can anyone help me?

Comment: @T_Bacon, you should write your comment as a question. Should be a workable solution

Comment: @PeterHorsbøllMøller - done.

Answer (score 1):

There is a 'Samples' folder which comes with your MapBasic installation. Within that, under .NET, there is GoogleConnect. This contains the **source code** for the GELink utility which I assume is what you would use to export the data manually. This would be a good place to start. As for the symbology, Google and MapInfo have different symbol sets, but I think they are both customisable so you could probably get these to match up with a bit of work.

Comment: There are a lot of source codes.

Comment: Yes, it's not a simple function but a collection of subs and functions which should give you a start towards building this conversion into your own application. The alternative is writing your own conversion script. The KML format is well documented by Google (https://developers.google.com/kml/) if you do want to roll your own, but why reinvent the wheel if someone has already done the work for you?

Comment: I agree with you, It is too difficult for me to understand. I will use the builtin function of MapInfo instead of rewriting the code.